# Using QtSpim to read a .txt file and edit it to have proper capitalization in assembly code

Tags: assembly, mips, xor, qtspim

```
.data
fnf:    .ascii  "The file was not found: "
###important: UPDATE THIS PATH TO WHERE YOU SAVED THE TEXT FILE
#asciiz directive creates null-terminated string
file:   .asciiz "C:/Users/mmono/OneDrive/Documents/input.txt" 
pstring:.asciiz " characters.\nFile contents:"
buffer: .space 1024     
    .text

# These lines opens and reads the file containing text to be modified
main:
    li  $v0, 13     # System call to open file, $v0 set to file descriptor
                # $v0 negative if failed to open file
    la  $a0, file   # Load file to read, $a0 set to address of string
                # containing file name
    li  $a1, 0      # Set read-only flag
    li  $a2, 0      # Set mode
    syscall
    add $s0, $v0, $zero # Save file descriptor in $v0 to new register $s0
                # because $v0 will be used in other system calls
    blt $v0, 0, err # Go to handler if failed to open file

# These lines read text from file
read:
    li  $v0, 14     # System call to read file
    add $a0, $s0, $zero # Load file descriptor to $a0
    la  $a1, buffer # Set $a1 to address of input buffer where
                # text will be loaded to
    li  $a2, 1024   # Set $a2 to number of characters to read
    syscall
    #after read, $v0 will have number of bytes read
    #set last byte to null
    la  $a0, buffer
    add $a0, $a0, $v0   #address of byte after file data
    sb  $zero, 0($a0)

#initialize some registers
init:
    li  $t0, 0      # $t0 will be message character iterator i
                # initialize i=0
    add $s1, $a1, $zero # save address start of buffer

#loop to count characters, exclude white spaces and 
loop:
    add $s2, $s1, $t0   # $s2 <= A + i, address of current character
                # A: address start of buffer
    lb  $s3, 0($s2) # load char in message[i] to $s3
    beq $s3, $zero, print   #null, reached end of buffer
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1 #i++
    j   loop        #continue counting

# Print Data to console
print:
    li  $v0, 1      # System call to print integer
    add $a0, $t0, $zero # Load to $a0 integer to print
    syscall
    #print "File contents:"
    li  $v0, 4      # System call to print string
    la  $a0, pstring    # Load to $a0 string to print
    syscall
    #print actual file contents
    li  $v0, 4      # System call to print string
    la  $a0, buffer # Load to $a0 string to print
    syscall

# Close File
close:
    li  $v0, 16     # Close File Syscall
    add $a0, $s0, $zero # Load File Descriptor
    syscall
    j   done        # Goto done

# Error
err:
    li  $v0, 4      # System call to print string
    la  $a0, fnf    # Load Error String
    syscall

# Done
done:
    li  $v0, 10     # Exit Syscall
    syscall
```

---

This is the file that this program reads. It is called input.txt.

this is very informative, but i wish there were more pictures
WOW!!!!!!!!!!! LIKE SO COOL!
I think you should write a follow up article that expands on the issue. We need more insightful opinion like yours.
GREAT! WRITE ANOTHER!

---

The program needs to edit the .txt file so that The first letter after a period, a linefeed (newline), exclamation point, or question mark is capitalized, and get rid of all the unwanted capitalization.

I know I am suppose to uses ASCII codes and xor the bits to change the ASCII character and then convert to a letter. This is because the bit sequence “00100000” 32 in decimal can be used with the logical operator "XOR" to change capitalization.

The 8-bit ASCII representation for
the uppercase letter “A” is 01000001. If you XOR this with 0010000, you will get 01100001, the ASCII code for lower case “a”.

But I can only perform this operation on the letters, all the special characters stay the same.

So I think I need to use some code like this:
xori $s3,$s3,32

Not sure how to implement this in my program though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need two functions called `swap_case` and another called `end_of_sentence`.

What do these help you do? Well you will need to call `end_of_sentence` on every character you read from the file. What this should do is to return 1 or 0 depending on if the character read is one of ".", "?", "!", "\n".

The other function simply takes a character and converts the case to the other case. The way you use this is that it is only called if a character is not in the correct case.

I will get you started with the first function

```
end_of_sentence:
  li $v0, 1
  beq $a0, '.', eos_ret
  beq $a0, '?', eos_ret
  beq $a0, '\n', eos_ret
  beq $a0, '!', eos_ret
  li $v0, 0    
  eos_ret: jr $ra
```

You can decide how you implement the second function. There are many ways.

I think one more useful one is this

```
isalpha:
  li $v0, 0
  blt $a0, 65, isalpha_ret
  bgt $a0, 122, isalpha_ret
  li $v0, 1
  bge $a0, 97, isalpha_ret
  ble $a0, 90, isalpha_ret
  li $v0, 0
  isalpha_ret: jr $ra
```